# CSS font-family: Which name does css font use?

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, font-family

I intended to change Google Chrome's language specify default (fallback) font to [Noto Sans CJK](http://www.google.com/get/noto/). But it turns out that my Chrome does not support it. I have the whole family of Noto Sans+Serif installed on my Windows 8.

I've tried some fonts using an empty html, many of the fonts work, but still there's some that do not work.

FONT-FAMILY:

- "Segoe UI" [ok]
- "Segoe Print" [ok]
- "Microsoft YaHei" [ok] (family name) (stock zh-Hans font)
- "Microsoft YaHei Light" (Family name) (stock) [fail]
- "MicrosoftYaHeiLight" (Postscript name) [fail]
- "Noto Sans" (Family Name) [ok]
- "Noto Sans S Chinese Regular" (full name) [fail]
- "Noto Sans S Chinese" (family) [fail]
- "NotoSansHans-Regular" (PostScript Name) [fail]
- "1.000;ADBE;NotoSansHans-Regular;ADOBE" (Unique Identifier) [fail]

** all the fonts have been installed before testing.*

The only way to use these fonts seems to be using `@font-face{}`, but I do not think there's a way to  apply `@font-face{}` in Chrome's default font settings.

---- Update ----

All screenshots are taken in a brand new Chrome profile.
Font is recognised by Chrome, but no font is displayed correctly other than the one defined with `@font-face{}`

[image: Imgur]
*Font setting page, the font shown should be just Arial.*

[image: Imgur]
*Test page shows that the font cannot be displayed by Chrome by using `font-family`.*

Comment: What is "does not support"? Can't you choose _Noto Sans_ from the Standard Font menu? Or can you, but it doesn't show this font on the screen? If the latter, you should check if you don't have a "user stylesheet" (maybe as part of a downloaded theme), and if the font does contain the characters you're trying to display.

Comment: @MrLister Tried to rephrase my question and make the idea clearer.

Comment: CSS specs seem to be silent about font family name interpretation for normal `font-family` declarations. For `@font-face` rules, CSS3 Fonts specifies that a name in `local` declarations is used to “match only the Postscript name or the full font name in the name table of locally available fonts” and that only family names be used (e.g., no “Light” specifier – font weight is to be handled separately). In implementations, the situation seems to be rather messy especially for light typefaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really encounter this problem too，i use PostScript Name make it on screen. like this:

font-family:"SourceHanSansCN-ExtraLight";
or
font-family:"SourceHanSansCN-Light";

But, I can use noto sans Thin anyway.

"NotoSansSChinese-Thin";   disable
"Noto SansS Chinese"; weight：100   able, but use thin (equal ExtraLight in Source Han Sans Cn)